# Browser Chrome: dijit validationTextBox shows blue bar in background on double clicking outside textbox and then clicking inside textbox

Tags: google-chrome, dojo, click, double, focus

I am using dojo validationTextBox and on focus event, value in textbox need to be wiped out. But when user double clicks near textbox then textbox gets selected and then if user clicks inside textbox, blue bar apprears in the textbox background. This blue bar dont go away even when user clicks outside of textbox.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html >
        <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/_static/js/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

        <script>dojoConfig = {async: true, parseOnLoad: true}</script>
        <script src='https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/_static/js/dojo/dojo.js'></script>

        <script>
            require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"]);
        </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function wipeMeOut(){
                    dijit.byId("phone").set("value","");
                }
            </script>
        </head>

</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div>
        <label for="phone">Phone number, no spaces:</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"  value="someTestString"
        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
        data-dojo-props="regExp:'[\\w]+', invalidMessage:'Invalid Non-Space Text.'" onfocus="wipeMeOut()"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```